# Can/should Ruby on Rails tests persist to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a DailyQuestionSet model and a method in it that (is supposed to) go to the database, see if a DailyQuestionSet already exists for that day, if so, return it, or if not, create a new one, save it to the database and return it.

This seems to work when I call it from a Controller but not from a Ruby on Rails automated test of the model. I am not sure if I'm going crazy or missing something.

When

```
class DailyQuestionSet < ApplicationRecord

 def DailyQuestionSet.get_today_dailyquestionset

    @dailyquestionset = nil
    @questionlist = nil

    @dailyquestionset_list = DailyQuestionSet.where('posed_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, DateTime.now.end_of_day).all

    if @dailyquestionset_list.empty?

      @dailyquestionset = DailyQuestionSet.create!(posed_date: DateTime.now)
      @dailyquestionset.save!

    else

      raise "disaster"
    end

    return @dailyquestionset

  end
end
```

```
class DailyQuestionSetTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "make sure today's daily_question_set has been deleted by the setup function" do
    # later add function to delete today's daily_question_set so we can create it and then make sure get_today_dailyquestionset has created it once and then we can refer back to the same row
  end

  test "create daily_question_set and make sure it has questions" do

    @dailyquestionset = DailyQuestionSet.get_today_dailyquestionset

    ....

  end

  test "create daily_question_set and make sure it has the same questions" do

    @dailyquestionset = DailyQuestionSet.get_today_dailyquestionset

    ....

  end

end
```

What I thought this would do is add a row to the daily_question_sets table in the database every time I run the first test, and then retrieve that row when I run the second test.

But when I look at the test database there's no row in there being created. I think maybe Rails is not committing the transaction to the database?

Or, put more simply, the `raise "disaster"` exception never gets thrown because get_today_dailyquestionset always returns a new DailyQuestionSet and never gets the one it (should have) created from the database.

I think I might be fundamentally misunderstanding testing in Rails. Should I be messing around with the DB in model tests at all?

Answer (score 0):

Test database is erased on each run and each individual test runs it queries as transactions so you can't share objects from one test to the other.

If you need objects shared between tests use a `setup` block https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#putting-it-together or just run both queries one after the other on the same individual test.

Comment: Thanks - useful to know that the test DB is erased after each run (I presume that means after all the tests are completed). That still doesn't quite solve how the method in the model can work though as unless this newly created object is persisted to the DB the model logic doesn't make sense / work.

Comment: The objects are indeed persisted, but only during each test life span. You can't create an object on one test to use it on another test, but you can sure call the method twice on the same test to test what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your tests are set up. Most likely, you have a separate test database for when the test suite is being run. Try running `sqlite3 <app-name>_test`, from the command line, if you are using the default Rails database solution. If you wanted to view the development database, you would run `sqlite3 <app-name>_development`.

Comment: Thanks - I have tried download both the test and development database files into DB Browser and the rows are not being created in there. Or they are being created in there and then deleted!